# MSD String Sort algorithm produces an almost correct result

Tags: python, sorting

For an application, Im experimenting with various sorting methods. The first is an MSD String sort that sorts everything correctly except the first item. The code is contained within [this](https://gist.github.com/IoDmitri/79e98201e78f6bb92d0c) gist

The following non sequitur `['I','need','a','sentence','that','will','produce','a','sentence', 'at','least','twenty',
    'characters','long','this','is','currently','fifteen','foot','long']`
sorts into the following:
`['I', 'a', 'a', 'at', 'characters', 'currently', 'fifteen', 'foot', 'is', 'least', 'long', 'long', 'need', 'produce', 'sentence', 'sentence', 'that', 'this', 'twenty', 'will']`

Comment: It would be helpful to give an example of the unsorted input and incorrectly sorted output in the body of your Question, to illustrate the all-but-first-item correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any capital letter comes before a lower case letter, so in this case a capital I is actually the smallest which means that this sorting algorithm works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

All characters have a corresponding numerical value.  That's how python can sort them; it's just ordering the numerical values of the letters lowest to highest.

See, for example, ASCII encoding: http://www.asciitable.com/
The uppercase letters come first in the table so they have a lower value, and are therefore given priority in your sorting algorithm.